Azure Kubernetes Cluster Terraform Set Disk Type
I have a kubernetes service running in azure and deployed using terraform as follow:
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  location            = var.location
  name                = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-${var.aks_name}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  dns_prefix          = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-${var.aks_name}"
  kubernetes_version  = "1.28.5"
  node_resource_group = "${azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name}"
  sku_tier = var.cluster_sku_tier

  default_node_pool {
    name                 = "systempool"
    vm_size              = "Standard_D2ds_v5"
    orchestrator_version = "1.28.5"
    zones                = [2, 3]
    enable_auto_scaling  = true
    min_count            = 1
    max_count            = 2
    os_disk_size_gb      = var.disk_size
    
    type                 = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.system_pool_subnet.id
    temporary_name_for_rotation = "resize"
    max_pods = 35
    node_labels = {
      "nodepool-type" = "System"
      "environment"   = "${var.environment}"
      "nodepoolOS"    = "linux"
      "app"           = "System"
      "nodepool" = "vm001"
    }

    upgrade_settings {
      max_surge = "10%"
    }
  //Other default configurations
  ....
  }


everything works fine but i realised that this code by default set the vm disk to Premium SSD which i dont need it and wanted to deploy it with a Standard Disk, which is also cheaper compared to the SSD.
On Terraform documentations i couldnt find anything if not the os_disk_type. While browing different topic and sites, someone mentioned that as the VM is premium, by default terraform picks up the Premium Disk if is available. Is this true?
I was wondering if anyone knows how can i change the Disk From the Default Premium SSD to a Standard?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide


Azure Kubernetes Cluster Terraform Set Disk Type
by default terraform picks up the Premium Disk if is available. Is this true?

Yes, you cannot change the disk type to Premium SSD or Standard HDD. By default, it will use premium storage for better performance.
The OS disk type will be selected automatically based on the Standard_DS3_v2 node VM size you chose in the configuration
In Terraform, you need to select the node pool as described below. Follow the MS Doc by AlaaBarqawi_MSFT for details.
  default_node_pool {
    name       = "agentpool"
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
    node_count = var.node_count
  }


Alternatively, you can change the disk type to Standard HDD after creating the AKS cluster. To do this, go to the VM, change the VM disk to Standard HDD, and restart the VM. For detailed instructions, follow the GitHub link by jdudleyie.
